# Descending chain property for compact Lie goups

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, geometric-representation-theory

I'm searching for a good reference that prove the descending chain propriety for compact Lie groups (i.e. every sequence $K_1\supset K_2\supset...$ of closed subgroups $K_i$ of $G$ is eventually constant).

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Am I missing something, or does it follow from the fact that a closed subgroup is either a union of connected components or of lower dimension, and by compactness the number of connected components is finite, while by Lieness, the dimension is finite?

Comment: Yes! What I have not found is a proof of the fact that a closed subgroup is either a union of connected components or of lower dimension. 
Thanks!

Comment: The follows from the fact that a closed subgroup is a Lie subgroup, and so its identity component is determined by its Lie algebra.

Comment: Thank you @BenMcKay! 
Is my argumentation correct?
If I have H closed subgroup of G then H is a submanifold. Now I have two possibilities: dim(H)=dim(G) or dim(H)<dim(G). If dim(H)=dim(G) then H is also an open submanifold of G (is it true that it simply follows from the definition of submanifold?), thus H has less connected components than G.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.